# CORS fetch authentication using Browser's session cookie

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, cors, session-cookies

I have a server that stores session cookies and you can log onto it using a page (foo.com/login.html) that runs in the browser. The browser then stores a session cookie for this domain.

Now I want another page (bar.com) upon initialization to make a GET request using JavaScript to the first page (foo.com/authenticate) which should check if a session cookie exists in the browser and validate it, if correct he should respond with the session's username (however this is retrieved from the cookie). Of course I cannot check in bar.com's JavaScript if there exists a session cookie for foo.com.

Trying to solve this I ran into a few problems, one of which is of course CORS. I managed to avoid this problem by placing a reverse proxy in front of foo.com that adds all required CORS headers to the response. besides adding the headers, the proxy only tunnels requests through (eg. rev-proxy.com/authenticate -> foo.com/authenticate)

Now when I call the handler through the rev proxy from just another browser window directly (eg. rev-proxy.com/authenticate), I get the correct response. The handler from foo.com's backend finds the session cookie, reads out the username and passes it back. BUT when I try to make the same call from JavaScript inside bar.com (fetch("rev-proxy.com/authenticate")), I receive null, meaning he did not find the cookie (note that the request itself has status 200, meaning it did reach the backend of foo.com).

I have the feeling I am missing a crucial point in how cookies are used by browsers but I cannot find any useful information on my specific problem since I believe it is a rather unusual one.

Comment: You should provide a real [mcve]

Comment: Why the proxy in the first place? Why is `foo.com/authenticate` not returning the proper CORS headers itself to begin with? (If what you are doing is an intended use case, then any argument “can’t be done at this point” would be rather absurd, IMHO.)

Comment: You are right and it is absurd. But adding the proxy was actually a lot simpler than adding the headers. I can just say that the backend of foo.com is an external service that is rather limiting when you do not want to touch its core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

> fetch won’t send cookies, unless you set the credentials init option. (Since Aug 25, 2017. The spec changed the default credentials policy to same-origin. Firefox changed since 61.0b13.)

Comment: Thank you that did the trick: I added `credentials: 'include'` and set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: bar.com`